# how to pass custom parameters to a function like in MVC html.routeurl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

I have written a small extension method to Html Helper library as follows:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url, string alt)
{
    var img = new TagBuilder("img");
    img.MergeAttribute("src", url);
    img.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
    return new MvcHtmlString(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

I want to change it so I can add parameters as I require. Something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url, object htmlParameters)
{
    var img = new TagBuilder("img");
    img.MergeAttribute("src", url);

    //Now I would like to extract the properties (and their values) from the object
    //and add them to img.

    return new MvcHtmlString(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

I want to make this function generic and pass an `object` with custom properties and apply those properties to the `img` tag. Like we pass the `htmlParameters` to `ActionLink` helper method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "actionName","controllerName", new {@class = "class"})
```

whats the trick for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can extract them by using following code:

```
var attributes = (IDictionary<string, object>) HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)
img.MergeAttributes<string, object>(attributes, replaceExisting:true);
```

hope this help.